# Generate a sound - PCM (Android - Java)

Tags: android, audio, byte, pcm

I've found here on stackoverflow.com [a great example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9106394/859646) that actually works for playing sounds.
Everything works smoothly but I'd like to know what happen in PCM generation.
Here is the code:

```
int idx = 0;
for (final double dVal : sample) {
    final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767));

    generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
    generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
}
```

where sample is a double array that holds a sine computed with all required parameters in this case (frequency, hertz, so on and so forth), and generatedSnd is a byte array.
Everything I know is that val & 0xff translates an int into a byte, but here what is precisely done? Why do there is the shift >>> 8?

Comment: Just guessing...It saves lowest 8-bit in the first byte, then it saves the higher 8-bit (from 9 to 16) in the second byte? Is it correct? Then what dVal * 32676 means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't mention in your question what the input to this function is, but I'm going to guess that the elements in `sample` have a range of -1.0 to +1.0.

16-bit signed PCM data has a range of -32768 to +32767. So what's happening in this method is that each floating point sample is scaled by 32767 to get a value in the range -32767 to +32767, which is then truncated to a `short`.

This `short` is then stored in `generatedSnd` (which I assume to be a `byte[]`) by first writing the low `byte`of the `short` (the least significant 8 bits), followed by the high byte (shifting the short 8 bits to the right takes what originally was the high byte and places it in the low byte).

Comment: Your guess was right, sample's elements have the range you mentioned. Thank you very much for the good explanation! EDIT: generateSnd was byte[numSamples*2], as you said